# Client program that can connect to multiple servers simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have written a rudimentary server client program using sockets programming in JAVA. The server is multithreaded and can accept many client connections at once. The clients however are not multithreaded. The clients can upload, download, read, write and delete files from the server. I run the programs in the command prompt window so they don't have any external user interface. Up to this point my program works fine.

I now want to make the client multithreaded as well so that it can simultaneously connect to multiple servers. I then want the client to be able to send requests to the servers. The client can choose which server to send the request to among the many servers it might be connected with.

With that in mind I changed the client code to have multiple threads. But I dont know how I can choose between servers while the program is running. Is there a way to switch between threads at will in JAVA(while the program is running), so that I can choose which thread processes my request?

Comment: So you're planning to have one thread per server the client is connected to? You could give each thread a blocking queue of requests to process and have the user thread put jobs on those queues. But there's no reason you need a thread per server; you just need as many threads as you want to execute simultaneous operators, so if it's only one operation with a choice of server you don't need multiple threads. Or you can have a small number of threads in an executor pool to perform the operations on your set of server connections.

Comment: if I connect the client to three servers for example then automatically the client will need at least three threads right?

Comment: Not necessarily, although in practice it may depend on the protocol you're using and how long operations you issue might block. There's no reason a single thread can't monitor many TCP connections though and respond asynchronously to them. But a thread per client connection can work well, and (usually) threads are cheap.

Comment: so how can i switch between threads from the client program? The client program might be connected to server1 and server2. It might want to send a read file request to server 1 now and later send a download request to server2. How do i specify in Java which server gets the download request and which gets the read request, while keeping the connection of both servers alive and persistent so that after these operations are finished, the client can send additional requests again to any of the two servers?

Comment: You don't switch in that sense. The threads run independently; you'll need to come up with a way to pass instructions to them and for them to pass results, progress, etc. back to your main thread / UI thread.

Comment: that is exactly my question bro... How do i choose which thread the instruction will be passed to? (Is there a method in java that lets me specify a thread by name and call it by name? )

Comment: You need to set up some kind of queue for each thread, and each thread checks that queue periodically. The main thread puts instructions in the queue X to target thread X'. Someone more proficient in Java could point the best class/technique to do that, but the basic mechanism is around that.

Comment: @1xQ When you go to a restaurant, do you choose who cooks your food? Or does each cook know what work they're supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

Here is some kind of skeleton how you could do this:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Connection w1 = new Connection("localhost", 2346);
         w1.start();

         Connection w2 = new Connection("localhost", 2346);
         w2.start();

         Connection w3 = new Connection("localhost", 2347);
         w3.start();

         w1.sendMessage("Hello ");
         w2.sendMessage("Coffee ");
         w1.sendMessage("world!");
         w2.sendMessage("break!");
         w3.sendMessage("Beer!");

         w1.terminate();
         w2.terminate();
         w3.terminate();
    }
}
```

As long as you don't use busy waiting its ok to handle every connection in a new thread:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class Connection implements Runnable {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private PrintWriter os;

    private volatile boolean running = false;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue;

    public Connection(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
    };

    public void start() {
        try {
            this.os = new PrintWriter(new Socket(host, port).getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }

        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(running) {
            // send messages in queue
            while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
                os.print(queue.poll());
            }
            // wait to be notified about new messages
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                terminate();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void sendMessage(String msg) {
        queue.add(msg);
        this.notify();
    }

    public void terminate() {
        running = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }
}
```